# Exchange 2013 Hybrid Configuration Wizard

Tags: exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

I have an issue with the Hybrid Configuration wizard. Currently my organization has:

- 1 Ex 2013
- 2 EX 2007

We are rolling out to an Hybrid environment with office 365 Using Ex 2013. All the Virtual Directories including Autodiscover records are pointing to the on premise EX 2013 server correctly.

One of the Prerequisites for the Hybrid was to install Cumulative Update 6 on Ex2013 as there was an error on the Wizard.

Since Upgrading when i try to re run the wizard i receive the below error:

The wizard did not complete successfully. Please see the list below for error details.
Federation certificate with the thumbprint "A27A5D1D0F7BCAB4B5DDD75BD7CFFF36594C14E3" cannot be found.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: I have just ran cmdlet in powershell called Test-FederationCertificate. I have notice that the certificate is not installed

Comment: I have fixed the issue had to remove the federation link and re-enable and now i am able to proceed with the the HCW.